# how to use numpy to receive a readable Kirchhoff matrix array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
gnm = GNM('synthetase')
gnm.buildKirchhoff(calphas)
gnm.getKirchhoff()

array([[ 5., -1., -1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ -1., 7., -1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ -1., -1., 15., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
.........,
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 9., -1., -1.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., -1., 12., -1.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., -1,. -1., 11.]])

data = gnm.getKirchhoff()
np.savetxt('outfile.txt', data, fmt='%1.4e')
```

From using the numpy savetxt command above, I got a .txt file that essentially has the matrix array, but it is almost unreadable because it has too many 0s crowding the rest of the numbers. Is it possible to output the array to a txt file such that the array will look like the one generated above and not contain 0.000000e+00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the "fmt" argument to `np.savetxt`, and use the 'g' format, rather than 'e'. 'e' forces scientific notation in every case, but 'g' uses the general format-- choosing the appropriate display based on the number.

```
np.savetxt('outfile.txt', data, fmt='%1.4g')
```

To learn more about how to format strings, the "Formatting Mini-Language" is the place to look:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: I think you have an extra quote here, don't you?